# Types for mapping object with property based return type on callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a type-safe `mapObject` function.

The first parameter is the object to transform and the second is a callback function with one parameter with two properties - `path` and `value`. Path is a dot notation string of a key on the object, and value returns the value of that property (further explained in comments in the code below). The callback should then return the type of the same property but from the R type (which is the type the object mapping should return).

However, I get the error that `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite` when using the `MakeOverloads` type, and not sure how to go about fixing this issue.

I also want to note that it would be okay if the function should be limited to only mapping the top level properties - if the type is too complex for multiple levels of nesting, as even if it only worked for one level, it could be used recursively and the types would be correct still.

*TS Playground available [here](https://tsplay.dev/NBVDxN).*

```
type UnionToIntersection<
  T,
  U = T extends unknown ? { _: { [_ in T & PropertyKey]: never } } : {},
  V = keyof U[keyof U],
  X = true extends (T extends PropertyKey ? true : never) ? never : PropertyKey
> = T extends never ? never : V extends X & infer W ? W : V;

type Flatten<T, Z extends string = ""> = T extends object
  ? UnionToIntersection<
      {
        [P in keyof T]: P extends string | number
          ? T[P] extends object
            ? Flatten<T[P], `${Z}${P}.`>
            : { [Q in `${Z}${P}`]: T[P] }
          : never;
      }[keyof T & (T extends readonly unknown[] ? number : unknown)]
    >
  : T;

type MakeOverloads<T, R extends Record<keyof T, unknown>> = UnionToIntersection<
  {
    [K in keyof T]: {
      ({ path, value }: { path: K; value: T[K] }): R[K];
    };
  }[keyof T]
>;

const mapObject = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  R extends Record<keyof T, unknown>,
>(obj: T, cb: MakeOverloads<Flatten<T>, Flatten<R>>): R => {
  return {} as any;
}

type ExampleType = {
  user: {
    address: {
      number: number,
      country: string,
    },
    age: number,
  },
  followers: number,
}

type ExampleReturnType = {
  user: {
    address: {
      number: number,
      country: string,
    },
    age: string,
  },
  followers: number,
}

const exampleInput: ExampleType = {
  user: {
    address: {
      number: 12,
      country: "Norway",
    },
    age: 242,
  },
  followers: 391,
};

// path should be 'user.address.number' | 'user.address.country' | 'user.age' | 'user.followers'
// value should be the value of the property specified in path
const test = mapObject<ExampleType, ExampleReturnType>(exampleInput, ({ path, value }) => {
  if (path === "user.address.country") {
    value.split("");
  }

  // should return the value for the key in ExampleReturnType
  if (path === "user.age") {
    return `${value} years`;
  }

  return value;
});
```

I originally wanted the return type to be automatic - however I could only get that working with a type where the object has the same shape, but every property could be *any* of the types returned from callback. Thought it worth mentioning in-case anyone knows some magic to get this working too.

I've also tried another version of this, which you can see on [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAg5Zw) TS Playground, which gets the same error but the error appears first when using the function.

Comment: Before I even think of wading into this: why are you trying to describe the callback as overloads?  There's no way the compiler will verify that the implementation works, so you'd need type assertions or something, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/WGB7om).  I don't know I really see the point in resolving deeply recursive types just to produce a type that doesn't actually meet the underlying use case.  How should we proceed here?